# Upgrading android studio causing my flutter application to only display a white screen

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I decided that today I would upgrade android studio and all of the recommended upgrades for a flutter application I am working on.  After doing this, when I run the app over usb on an android device with "flutter run --verbose", I get a white screen on my phone with the following error:

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to
           http://127.0.0.1:63958/aZGMSZRNaEY=/

On the following github help page(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25112) I found the solution that seems to be working for people:

"One of the causes of this error is Android 9. In this version all Unity3D http requests stopped working.
Http request are disabled by default in Android 9.
In flutter I installed Android 8.1.
Another solution is to tweak AndoidManifest.xml adding in application usesCleartextTraffic="true""

The problem is, I am not completely familiar with android and flutter and what would be the best thing to do.  Would someone mind giving me detailed instructions on how to do this and which one of these solutions would be best?  I have been using Atom IDE.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  After running flutter pub get I still encountered the following error:

Unhandled Exception: ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.

I fixed it by adding the following line as the first line in main() in main.dart:

WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

just run `flutter pub get` and uninstall and reinstall the application.
If the problem is still there just run `flutter doctor` and see the issues and the procedure to solve them

Comment: Hi @dadu mohapatra.  Thanks for helping me out!  I just tried this.  The first time I ran the application with --verbose I got no errors but still got just a white screen on my phone.  The second time I ran it I got the same error again.  I ran flutter doctor and did not pick up any issues.

Comment: Hi. Can i see the run window after coming to the white page

Comment: HI @dadu  mohapatra.  Thanks again.  I'm a little unsure of what you want.  Do you want terminal results or something on the phone?  If terminal results,  what command do you want me to run?

Comment: There is a window called run in the bottom of the android studio.There all the errors are printed so clicking on the run a terminal kind of window will be opened...I want to know what are the errors that are happening inside

Comment: Hi.  I am not using android studio,  I am simply using "flutter run --verbose".  What should I do?

Comment: You can send the things that are printed on the terminal during the white screen appears

Comment: Hi.  This time when I ran it I did not get the error in terminal but still got a white screen on my phone.  How should I send you the output?  In the comment box it says it is way too long.

Comment: It is not allowing me too.  When I copy and paste it thinks it is a picture and when I save it to a word document it still won't let me.  I opened an issue in github here:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47466.  I might be able to paste it there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rub application with latest fluttr SDK, [flutter sdk](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)